# mongodb grails simple application times out

Tags: mongodb, grails

I'm having an issue with mongodb 2.6.5 and grails 2.4.4 that I can't resolve.  For the sake of isolating the problem I created a simple 2.4.4 grails app, installed the grails mongodb plugin (compile ":mongodb:3.0.2"), commented out the hibernate dependencies, added my mongodb datasource, and set up a simple domain class (com.nerds.Nerd).  When I generate-all and then start the app and navigate to the NerdController CRUD page I get the following error every time:

> MongoTimeoutException occurred when processing request: [GET] /MONGO/nerd/index
> Timed out while waiting to connect after 10000 ms. Stacktrace follows:
> com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting to connect after 10000 ms

I can access mongo via http using `http://localhost:28017/`

I have also tested manually adding data and querying from mongo.  This all works fine.

In the debug log prior to the timeout it looks like GORM aquired a mongo session and then tried rolling back a transaction.

> DatastoreTransactionManager:128 - Found thread-bound Session [org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoSession@e47ee6] for Datastore transaction
>
> DatastoreTransactionManager:128 - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
>
> DatastoreTransactionManager:128 - Initiating transaction rollback
>
> DatastoreTransactionManager:128 - Rolling back Datastore transaction on Session [org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoSession@e47ee6]
>
> DatastoreTransactionManager:128 - Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction

Any insight would be helpful.  Thanks

edit:  The mongo datasource is pretty simple.  I'm using the correct port.

From the mongo log:

> 014-11-18T13:10:13.388-0900 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=17275 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 32-bit host=enterprise

from DataSource.groovy

> grails { mongo { host = 'localhost' port = 27017 databaseName = 'mydb' } }

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Linux enterprise 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu i686

Comment: look inside mongod log file and see if you can see your connections coming in.  I would also verify your mongodb status via mongo shell -- and then move on to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain the issue was on the mongod side.  I stopped the mongo daemon, put it into high verbose debug mode (using mongod -vvvv command), and when I tried to replicate the issue while watching the console output, the issue did not happen.  I'm not entirely sure what the exact cause of the timeout was, but its not happening now.  Thanks for the responses.